# How to filter JSON Data in backend DB using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, npm, jsondb

My backend JSON DB is running on http://localhost:3000/user and contains the following:

**db.json**

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Stephen",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Ireland"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "England"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Wales"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Scotland"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Simon",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "France"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Italy"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "USA"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "New Zealand"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Stephen",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "South Africa"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Ted",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Fiji"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": {},
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Chile"
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": {},
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Japan"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Namibia"
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "[Available]",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Portugal"
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Uruguay"
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "name": "Tony",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Tonga"
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "name": "",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Georgia"
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "name": "Simon",
      "profile": "[Unsplash URL Placeholder]",
      "team": "Samoa"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my JavaScript function, I want to send a HTTP GET request to the backend and filter the response to only show users which have an empty string in place of the name value. If true, I then want to send a PATCH request to update the JSON DB using the string which the user provided. If false, I want to alert the user. Here's what I currently have:

**index.html**

```
              <input class="appearance-none bg-transparent border-none w-full text-gray-700 mr-3 py-1 px-2 leading-tight focus:outline-none" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Jane Doe" aria-label="Full name" required>
              <button onclick="addNameTestTest()" type="submit" class="flex-shrink-0 bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 border-teal-500 hover:border-teal-700 text-sm border-4 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded" type="button">
                Sign Up
              </button>
```

**index.js**

```
function RandomNumber(min, max) {
    // Generate a random number between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
    //return Math.floor(Math.random()  (max - min + 1) + min);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
}

function addNameTestTest() {
    var randomNumber = RandomNumber(1,20)
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value
    var test = $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/user",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    })
    var data = JSON.parse(test)
    var yourMatch = data.user.find(c => c.name === "")
    if (yourMatch == true){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/user/"+randomNumber+"",
            method: "PATCH",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { 'name': name },
            success: function(name) {
                console.log(name);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Error: ' + status + ' - ' + error);
            }

        })
    } else {
        alert("Error: The team which you were assigned has already been taken or else all teams have been allocated. Please refresh your browser and try again.");
    }
}
```

However, when I test this, I receive the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse`

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWT7W.png)

Using jq and bash, I'd use the following to filter the data:

```
url="http://localhost:3000/user"
response=$(curl -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" $url)
responseTest=$(echo $response | jq '.[] | select(.name=="")')
echo $responseTest
```

If anyone could assist, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ajax` call is async, and returns a `promise` object.

Something like this `async/await` approach should get you going in the right direction:

```js
async function addNameTestTest() {
    ...
    var test = await $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/user",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'JSON'      
    })
}
```

Your other approach is to put all your following code into the `success` callback.  Javascript will not `wait` for the `ajax` call to resolve before moving on (by default), and that is your issue.

Comment: Hi, as per your suggestions, I updated my function but now I'm receiving the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>).

Is there an alternative method to parse?

Comment: I suggest opening your debug panel and viewing in the network tab exactly what the backend returns